# Publishing Meteor Users to Admin

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I'm trying to publish all emails and "roles" to "admin" users (using the meteor-roles meteorite package), and the server knows what it's trying to publish, but for some reason the client is not picking up the data. Here's the piece of code involved:

Server Code:

```
Meteor.publish("directory", function() {
   if(Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, 'admin')) {
      //next line shows that it outputs that there are 2 documents in this
      console.log(Meteor.users.find({}, {fields:{emails:1, roles:1}}).count());
      return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields:{emails:1, roles:1}});
   } else {
      return {};
   }
}
```

Client Code:

```
Meteor.subscribe("directory");
Directory = new Meteor.Collection("directory");

//and then to simulate my use for this collection
console.log(Directory.find().count());
//which outputs 0
```

Why isn't the client getting the documents? (and I am definitely logging in with an account with role "admin")

Thanks!

**EDIT and SOLUTION!**

Okay, so I figured out what I was doing wrong. I just need to publish "directory" on the server, and subscribe on the client. Then, all user data goes into the Meteor.users collection, and I shouldn't define my own "Directory=new Meteor.Collection('directory')". I can then access the data via Meteor.users. Cheers!

Server: use same code as above

Client:

```
Meteor.subscribe("directory");
console.log(Meteor.users.find().count()); //outputs 2, yay!
```

Answer (score 0):

Your collection should probably be defined on the beginning so that client knows where to write!

Also, your `Meteor.subscribe("directory");` runs once when the app is loaded. You should make it reactive.

```
Directory = new Meteor.Collection("directory");

Deps.autorun(function(){
  Meteor.subscribe("directory");
});
```

Comment: This isn't sufficient; the dependency function also has to touch userId somehow to indicate to Meteor that it should be rerun when the dependency changes. It can be as simple as function() {if Meteor.userId() {Meteor.subscribe('directory');}}.

Comment: For some reason neither of these are working. Directory on the client still contains 0 documents... My 2 other collections work fine, it's just this one because (I think) it involves users. Do I have to declare the collection "directory" on the server too or change some permissions somewhere? Even if I turn insecure and autopublish on, it still shows 0 documents in Directory

Comment: Oh, so you don't have this collection on the server? `publish("directory")` creates data channel, not a collection - data published from `Meteor.users` collection are found in the same collection on the client - so just use `Meteor.users.find()` as well, instead of `Directory.find()`. Do you have a reason why you want this collection to be different?